# How to handle multiple events to animate the same element in DOM?

Tags: javascript, dom, settimeout, setinterval, addeventlistener

I have a cube which should be scaled on keydown event for 3s, so this part is done, but the scale is gonna be broken if there is next keydown event when the previous event is not finished yet.

```
const cube = document.querySelector(".cube");
document.addEventListener("keydown", function (e) {
        // Here is the problem is taking place with multiple events
        cube.style.transform = "scale(1.1)";
        setTimeout(() => {
                cube.style.transform = "scale(1)";
        }, 3000);
    });
```

How do I handle multiple events by not creating multiple actions?
I hope you got the idea.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/animationend_event + promises https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises

Comment: Have you tried using a flag variable that you toggle true/false and react according to that boolean?

Comment: @charlietfl, yes I did, the same problem.